Can Steamcore Scholar discard two creatures with flying?
Steamcore Scholar can always discard two cards if you want it to right? I want to play it standard reanimator as just a straight 3 mana Careful Study on a body. But I can always discard two creatures with flying if I want to right?

Yes. The gather rulings clarify this:

You can discard an instant card, a sorcery card, a creature card with flying, or any two cards, even if one or both of those cards have the listed characteristics.


I never saw a rules ref for this one, do you have one?

The most relevant rule is 118.2 (and subrules). "Discard an instant or sorcery card, or a creature card with flying" is a cost that you can choose to pay. If you do not pay it, you are instead required to "discard two cards". Once you choose not to pay the cost, there are no constraints on which cards you can discard.

Sorry, I do have to develop the habit of reading gatherer rulings before asking a question.

Whenever you're directed to do A unless you do B, that means that you have the option to do B. Then, if you choose to not do B, or you are unable to do B[1], you must do A. Here, you are first given the option to discard an instant or sorcery card or a creature card with flying. Once you make the choice to not do so, you must discard two cards. If one or both of those cards turns out to be an instant or sorcery card or a creature card with flying, that doesn't change the fact that your initial choice was to not discard such a card.
[1] For instance, if a card says "Discard a card unless you pay 2 life", and you have a continuous effect that says that your life total can't change, then even if you decide to pay 2 life, you'll still have to discard a card, because the paying of 2 life didn't actually happen. On the other hand, if it said "Lose 2 life unless you discard a card", you could choose to not discard a card, and then the "lose 2 life" wouldn't take effect.

This seems like the kind of answer that would greatly benefit from a rules citation, given its technical nature. In the absence of such, it reads purely as an individual interpretation rather than a reliable answer.
